# Active Directory reset password

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2012-r2

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity DistinguishedName -NewPassword $NewPassword -Reset
Set-aduser DistinguishedName -changepasswordatlogon $true 
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity DistinguishedName
```

This is how a script resets a users password. It works as intended. The question is how to make it so the new password it is reset to, only lasts for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no parameter to define an expiration time (or date) for a password to be changed after a reset is done I would create a Group Policy (GPO) to enforce an "expiration after reset policy" and then assign that GPO to a group named "ExpirationPass" for that purpose.

Finally would use Add-ADGroup​Member (Remove-ADGroup​Member) cmdlets in the script to move the users to my "ExpirationPass" group to enforce the policy

Good luck!

Comment: would create a Group Policy (GPO) to enforce an "expiration after reset policy" This sounds like what I'm looking for, where is this GPO located? I've looked under computer configuration > security settings > account policies and don't see anything similar.

Comment: Well that should be done with the AD tools, starting with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/windows-firewall/create-a-group-policy-object

Comment: ... just quickly googled a bit looking for a video showing the full process of creating a GPO and assign to a group, found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=975iiX3jQcQ  ... not really good but clear enough to understand the concept

Comment: If the answer has been usefull I'll appeciate your acceptance, thanks.

Comment: I've looked under computer configuration > security settings > account policies and don't see anything similar, I must be blind I don't see anything referring to  "expiration after reset policy" - I understand the concept of applying a GPO